Maintain the checked state of the items of a CheckedListBox while searching
I have a CheckedListBox in a UserControl where data is input from a database.
While searching items, the checked boxes get unchecked. I have tried many times to solve it but throws an exception.
Initially searching is working fine. Problem is with the check state.
private DataTable GetDataTable()
{
    var dt = new DataTable();

    using (var CON = new SqlConnection("Connectionstring"))
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("Select Property_Name, Property_Id from property", CON))
    using (var da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
    {
        CON.Open();
        da.Fill(dt);
    }

    return dt;
}
private void Searchtext_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
        if (checkedListBox1.DataSource is DataTable dt)
        {

            var str = Searchtext.Text.Trim();

            dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = string.IsNullOrEmpty(str)
            ? null
            : $"Property_Name LIKE '%{str}%'";
        
        }

}
private void LoadProperty()
{
    checkedListBox1.DisplayMember = "Property_Name";
    checkedListBox1.ValueMember = "Property_Id";
    checkedListBox1.DataSource = GetDataTable();
}

I have placed the code input for search.

The issue is likely occurring because every time you filter the data in the CheckedListBox, it reloads the DataSource, which causes the check states to reset.
I think that you can fix this by saving the check states of the items before applying the filter and restoring them afterwards, like so:
`
// store states before you filter
private Dictionary<int, bool> GetCheckedStates()
{
    var checkedStates = new Dictionary<int, bool>();

    for (int i = 0; i < checkedListBox1.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        var row = (DataRowView)checkedListBox1.Items[i];
        int propertyId = (int)row["Property_Id"];
        checkedStates[propertyId] = checkedListBox1.GetItemChecked(i);
    }

    return checkedStates;
}

// then restore check states
private void RestoreCheckedStates(Dictionary<int, bool> checkedStates)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < checkedListBox1.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        var row = (DataRowView)checkedListBox1.Items[i];
        int propertyId = (int)row["Property_Id"];

        if (checkedStates.ContainsKey(propertyId))
        {
            checkedListBox1.SetItemChecked(i, checkedStates[propertyId]);
        }
    }
}

private void Searchtext_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (checkedListBox1.DataSource is DataTable dt)
    {
        // Save current checked states
        var checkedStates = GetCheckedStates();

        var str = Searchtext.Text.Trim();
        dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = string.IsNullOrEmpty(str)
            ? null
            : $"Property_Name LIKE '%{str}%'";

        RestoreCheckedStates(checkedStates);
    }
}

private void LoadProperty()
{
    checkedListBox1.DisplayMember = "Property_Name";
    checkedListBox1.ValueMember = "Property_Id";
    checkedListBox1.DataSource = GetDataTable();
}

`
The thing is before applying filters you save the checked states of your items in a dictionary. The after filtering the data checked states are restored thanks to the dictionary.
Now the CheckedListBox preserves the checked items even when the filter is applied

Actually, this code is not working as expected. If I have checked boxes and search for a letter only the letters available within the search are remained checked even the search text box is null. But if I search for a new letter, all checked boxes get unchecked. I hope this is understandable.
